# Creating and Running RESTful Web Service on GlassFish

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey, jax-rs

I created a simple RESTful web service on the GlassFish server and run it according to this [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service.html) in the IntelliJ IDE. This runs fine based on the instruction provided. I have 2 additional questions,

a. The tutorial uses a service class provide below,

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getClichedMessage() {

        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I can access that from the `URL` provided,

```
http://localhost:8080/AppointmentManager_war_exploded/helloworld
```

Afterward, I add a new class in the same directory,

```
@Path("/")
public class App {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getMessage() {

        return "Hello, Berlin";
    }
}
```

I expected to see the message `"Hello, Berlin"` in the browser from the opening URL `http://localhost:8080/AppointmentManager_war_exploded/`, but, instead, I get the error provided,

```
HTTP Status 404 - Not Found
type Status report

messageNot Found

descriptionThe requested resource is not available.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.0
```

What is the issue here?

b. How do I change the part of URL `AppointmentManager_war_exploded` to something else, say, `appointment` etc? The `artifact` tab in the project setting is provided below,

[image]

I edited it, but, the change it not corresponded as expected.

I changed the project to `maven` build after the tutorial, but, the issue is not created for that. If someone interested, you can try too as it will take a minute to run.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**

> I expected to see the message "Hello, Berlin" in the browser from the opening URL http://localhost:8080/AppointmentManager_war_exploded/, but, instead, I get the error provided

In `MyApplication` class that provided by tutorial you should also add your new class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends Application{
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet h = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        h.add(HelloWorld.class);
        h.add(App.class);          // Add your new class here
        return h;
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to see expected page on `http://localhost:8080/AppointmentManager_war_exploded/`

**Second**

> How do I change the part of URL AppointmentManager_war_exploded to something else, say, appointment etc?

URL contains name of your artifact `AppointmentManager_war_exploded`. This artifact automatically copied to glassfish application directory. You can check `glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\__internal`.
Just change it just in project structure window here:

[image]

**Update**

Don't forget to change start URL in configuratin settings for app:

[image]

Comment: The answer is correct, but, the app still starts in the URL `http://localhost:8080/AppointmentManager_war_exploded/` which I was not able to change.